# How can I get the table names from the following query in sqlite c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

this is only returning the below, how can I capture the names of the tables in the DB

```
var tables = database.Query(map, "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'", ps);
```

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Comment: ive added in code, thanks for the help

Comment: have you tried just using "select * ..." and seeing what columns are returned?  Or using a query tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are having problems with the Mappings.

Another way you could get the table names is as follow:

Create a class with the following structure:

```
[Table("sqlite_master")]
public class SqliteMaster
{
    public SqliteMaster()
    {

    }

    [Column("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("tbl_name")]
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use the **Sqlite** `Table` method + `Linq` to extract the data.

Something like this:

```
var names = db.Table<SqliteMaster>()
              .Where(a => a.Type == "table")
              .Select(a => a.Name)
              .ToList();
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.-